# File exists Traceback when using 'x' mode to create a new file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new file using open, mode 'x' called my_file.txt, write a line into it, and then read the file. I am getting a traceback on the first line, stating that my_file.txt exists, where it does not. Your help is appreciated!

```
new_file = open("my_file.txt", 'x')
new_file.close()

new_file = open("my_file.txt", 'w')
new_file.write('Let us be happy')
new_file.close()

new_file = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
for line in new_file:
  line = line.strip()
  print(line)
```

Comment: mode `x` raises an exception if the file already exists, well, you getting that exception clearly indicates that the file does exist, just remove the first two lines, `w` (write mode) creates a file too

Answer (score 0):

x open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
and don't have to close file after each command just use "WITH" keyword to close file automatically.

Comment: please show some code please